# Is $x^3-ax-(2a+1)$ irreducible over $\Bbb Z$?

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Is the cubic polynomial $x^3-ax-(2a+1)$ irreducible over $\mathbb Z$ for all positive integers $a$?

one way to prove irreducibility is to use eisenstein's criterion. we want to find prime $p$ st:
$p\mid a$
$p\mid 2a+1$
$p^2\nmid 2a+1$
However, the first 2 conditions imply $p\mid 1$, a contradiction. so this approach fails.

another approach is to use the rational root thm.
let $x^3-ax-(2a+1)=(x+b)(x^2+cx+d)=x^3+(b+c)x^2+(bc+d)x+bd$
where b,c,d integers
$b+c=0$
$bc+d=-a$
$bd=-(2a+1)$

there was a link to a similar problem, now deleted.

Comment: Your current question as well as the linked question do not have any context. Please try to improve your question by adding relevant context.

Comment: No!! Context has to be part of the question body. I understand that you have acted here in good faith but note that while self answering the bar for standards is higher. For the current situation it is best to close the question unless improved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a cubic is reducible, then it must have a linear factor $x+b$, so $-b$ is an integer root.

$$-b^3+ab-(2a+1)=0$$
$$a(b-2)=b^3+1$$
$$a=\frac{b^3+1}{b-2}$$
$$(b-2)\mid 9$$
\begin{align}b-2&=-9,-3,-1,1,3,9\\b&=-7,-1,1,3,5,11\\b&\neq -1,1\end{align} so $(a,b,c)=(38,-7,11),(28,3,-19),(42,5,-17),(148,11,-27)$.

\begin{align}(x-7)(x^2+7x+11)&=x^3-38x-77\\ 
(x+3)(x^2-3x-19)&=x^3-28x-57\\ 
(x+5)(x^2-5x-17)&=x^3-42x-85\\ 
(x+11)(x^2-11x-27)&=x^3-148x-297\end{align}

so there are 4 $a$'s such that the cubic is reducible. Simply stating (but not deriving) one of the 4 factorizations is enough to disprove the question.

thanks to @dxiv for the suggestion.

Comment: Nice answer (+1), could use a bit more explanation at a few points.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why $b-2$ must divide $9$?

Comment: I see, because $a=\frac{b^3+1}{b-2}=b^2+2b-4+\frac{9}{b-2}$.

Comment: You can shorten the proof somewhat by noting that any rational root must be an integer since the polynomial is monic. Let $n$ be such a root, then $a=\frac{n^3-1}{n+2}$ and a similar argument follows.

Comment: @dxiv how did you derive $a=\frac{n^3-1}{n+2}$ ? did you compare coeffs too?

Comment: @cineel Regroup and collect: $\,n^3-an-(2a+1)=0 \iff n^3-1=(n+2)a\,$.